# How to transfer data between a class and the onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an int in the onCreate() method, and I would like to transfer the int into a class. How would I do that?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
int testInt = R.drawable.test;

}

public class myapplicationtest{
//I would like the int to be here
}
```

Note that they are both in the same activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
public static int testInt;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 testInt = R.drawable.test;

}
```

and

```
public class myapplicationtest{
//I would like the int to be here
int value = OnCreateClassName.testInt;
}
```

In that `OnCreateClassName` is class name for **testInt**

Answer (score 1):

In your activity create an instance of the class containing the testInt and set its value via a setter. For e.g.,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private myapplicationtest mytestInst = new myapplicationtest();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mytestInst.setInt(R.drawable.test);
    }

    public class myapplicationtest{
        private int testInt = 0;
        public void setInt(value) {
            testInt = value;
        }
        public int getInt() {
            return testInt;
        }
    }
}
```